# How to make SVG height animation from bottom of div to top?

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I am trying to make a SVG animation with line and circle. The line should be animated and the circle should move relative to the line height. The line should start at the bottom of div and after animated it should achieve with circle a top of div ad then should animate to bottom and again from bottom to top and from top to bottom all time with only one except - if user hover on circle it should stop, if user mouseover from circle it should start when it stop.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="171" height="728" viewBox="0 0 171 728">
<defs><style>.a{fill:#000;}</style></defs><circle class="a" cx="85.5" cy="85.5" r="85.5"></circle>
<rect class="a" width="7" height="0" transform="translate(82 113)">
<animate id="animation"
    attributeName="height"
    attributeType="XML"
    from="0" to="615"
    begin="0s" dur="5s"
    fill="freeze" />
<animate id="animation2"
    attributeName="height"
    attributeType="XML"
    from="615" to="0"
    begin="5s" dur="10s"
    fill="freeze" />
</rect>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Animations can have more than two states. For moving a value forth and back, you can write `values="728;113;728"`. You then need to define `keyTimes="0;.5;1"` to distribute these states across the simple duration - that means, all values need to be between 0 and 1, and if `dur="10s"`, the states will be reached in fractions of that time, i. e. 0s, 5s and 10s. The number of values in `keyTimes` and `values` must match.

To make an animation repeat endlessly, you need to set `repeatCount="indefinite"`.

Start and end times of animations can be relative to events. `end="stop.mouseenter"` means the animation will stop when the mouse enters the element with `id="stop"` (the circle). For restarting the animation, you can take advantage of the fact that animations can have more than one start time. `begin="0s;stop.mouseleave"` means it will start directly after loading, and also when the mouse leaves the element with `id="stop"`.

On stop, the animation is removed, so the line returns to its base state (no length), and will restart from there. This is obviously not the same as pausing the animation (freezing it in the state it has when the mouse hover starts), but your question didn't state if that is what you want to achieve. These declarative animations have no mechanism for pausing an animation. You would need a CSS animation for that, which would look different.

Finally, things get a bit easier if you use a `<line>` element instead of a `<rect>`. Then you only need to animate the `y1` attribute, moving it from the lowest point to the highest, and back again.

Note I have given the line a separate class, because it needs to have an explicit color and a width.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
}
.b {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="171" height="728" viewBox="0 0 171 728">
<defs><style>.a{fill:#000;}</style></defs>
<circle id="stop" class="a" cx="85.5" cy="85.5" r="85.5"></circle>
<line class="b" x1="85.5" y1="728" x2="85.5"  y2="728">
<animate id="animation"
    attributeName="y1"
    attributeType="XML"
    values="728;113;728"
    keyTimes="0;.5;1"
    begin="0s;stop.mouseleave"
    end="stop.mouseenter"
    dur="10s"
    repeatCount="indefinite" />
</line>
</svg>
</div>
```